# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable, Can't call function

Tags: python, string, function, dictionary, object

```
def add(n1, n2):
  return n1 + n2

def subtract(n1, n2):
  return n1 - n2

def multiply(n1, n2):
  return n1 * n2

def divide(n1, n2):
  return n1 / n2

operations = {
  "+": "add",
  "-": "subtract",
  "*": "multiply",
  "/": "divide"
}

num1 = int(input("What's the first number?: "))
num2 = int(input("What's the second number?: "))

for operation in operations:
  print(operation)

operation_symbol = input("Pick an operation from the line above: ")

calculation_function = operations[operation_symbol]
answer = calculation_function(num1, num2)


print(f"{num1} {operation_symbol} {num2} = {answer}")
```

It's giving the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 34, in <module>
    answer = calculation_function(num1, num2)
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

I think it's giving the error because I am using string from the dictionary but don't really know how to fix it.

Comment: Use the name of the function instead of the string: `{'+': add, '-': subtract, '*': multiply, '/': divide}`. In addition, there are already defined operator functions (`add`, `sub`, `mul`, `truediv`) in `operator`.

Answer (score 0):

`calculation_function` is being set to the value of your dictionary. These are all strings, thus it cannot be called like a function. Instead you should set the values in your dict to be the functions, not their string representations.

```
operations = {
  "+": add,
  "-": subtract,
  "*": multiply,
  "/": divide
}
```